# How do I capture weight updates while using tf.train.optimizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

How do I capture weight updates after a train step while using tf.train.optimizer?

One can get gradients, but I could not find any effective way other than finding the difference of weights from their previous copy. It becomes tedious as I have stored weights as a part of a dictionary, key being hidden layer, values being list of weights.

```
weights = {
'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}
biases = {
'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(sess.run(weights['h1']))
```

At the end of loop of each epoch.

Comment: This doesn't give the diff on each step

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to capture the snapshot of all trainable variables before and after a training step and get the difference:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
  ...

  def get_snapshot():
    return {var: value for var, value in zip(tf.trainable_variables(), session.run(tf.trainable_variables()))}

  ...

  snapshot_before = get_snapshot()
  session.run([optimizer], feed_dict={x: train_x, y: train_y})
  snapshot_after = get_snapshot()
  for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    print var.name, ' -> ', (snapshot_after[var] - snapshot_before[var])
```

This can look even nicer if implemented via a [context manager](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).
In terms of efficiency, this requires two extra `session.run()` invocations, however it's much better than evaluating each variable one by one.